# FutureBuilder shows [instance] instead of actual data

Tags: flutter

I want to download a list from firestore and display as a list in flutter widget.  The data is successfully downloaded (proved by the print(cp.data()).

However, the result shown is **[Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot']** instead of the actual carpark data.

Could anyone pls help point out what the bug is.

Thanks

```
class DownloadDataScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DownloadDataScreen createState() => _DownloadDataScreen();
}

class _DownloadDataScreen extends State<DownloadDataScreen> {
  List<DocumentSnapshot> carparkList = []; //List for storing carparks

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readFromFirebase();
  }

  Future readFromFirebase() async {
    // await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('carpark')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(
        (DocumentSnapshot cp) {
          carparkList.add(cp);

          print('printing cp');
          print(cp.data());
        },
      );
    });

    **return carparkList;**
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          'Car Park',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(

        future: readFromFirebase(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          List<Widget> children;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            children = <Widget>[
              const Icon(
                Icons.check_circle_outline,
                color: Colors.green,
                size: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}'),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ];
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            children = <Widget>[
              const Icon(
                Icons.error_outline,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
              )
            ];
          } else {
            children = const <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
              )
            ];
          }
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: children,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to call the function from the init because you already use the `FutureBuilder`.

Also, you don't need to cast it because when the future completes, the async snapshot already would provide you a list of `DocumentSnapshot` in the data and the .doc propertie.

Like this:

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  builder:(context,snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      /// here your data 
      snapshot.data.docs;
    }
)
```

Comment: Your first suggestion of removing the call "readfromFirebase()" is simple enough for me to understand and I have deleted it from "initState".  But what do you mean by "don't need to cast it"?  How the code should revised?  (I am quite a newbie in flutter.   ^_^ )   Thanks.

Comment: Pleasse check again my answer

Comment: My probelm solved!  Thank you very much!!